# A value of type "collection *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "recPtr"

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

I was coding some C programming and I came up with this error "a value of type "collection*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "recPtr".. and I don't know what the issue is.  Can someone help me please?  Much appreciated.

This is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#define MAX 150

typedef struct item {
    int itemId;
    char itemName[100];
    float price;
}itemRec;

typedef struct item* recPtr;

typedef struct collection {
    recPtr list;
    int size;
    int max;
}collectionRec;

int resizeCollection(collectionRec* coll, int max) {
    (*coll).list = (struct collection*)malloc(max * sizeof(struct collection));
    return true;
}
```

The error line is in the (*coll).list = (struct collection*)malloc(max * sizeof(struct collection));

Thank you

Comment: `(item*) != (collection*)` of course pointer types is different

Comment: You shall not cast the return value of `malloc`. In best case it hides errors. In other cases it causes your error.

Comment: @RbMm instead of (*coll).list = (struct collection*) I put (item*)!=(collection*) ?

Comment: I assume you want to resize the list, but not the collection. So you should use realloc: 
coll->list=(recPtr)realloc(col->list, max * sizeof (item))